# How do I do an .htaccess 301 redirect of a query string?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, 301-redirect, querystring

I'm trying to redirect a url http://domain.com/?p=106 to http://domain.com/?p=110

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=106
RewriteRule / http://domain.com/\?p=110 [L,R=301]
```

But I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, you need to check that `Options FollowSymLinks` is enabled before trying `rewrite` in a `.htaccess`. Then, you also have to note that the per-directory prefix is automatically removed, which means a pattern with `^/` never matches anything (I bet this is why your `/` doesn't work).

So, in your case, first check `Options FollowSymLinks` and then change the `RewriteRule` to be something as covener [suggested](https://serverfault.com/questions/319738/how-do-i-do-an-htaccess-301-redirect-of-a-query-string/319744#319744), or my version:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /?p=110
```

Answer (score 1):

RewriteRule / wouldn't match a request to / in htaccess.  The path you compare against is empty in that case (the prefix is stripped in htaccess rewriterule)

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain.com/?p=110
```